# VBA clean up conditional duplication of rows

Tags: string, vba, excel

I have a data set in which there is an id field and a number of other fields.

The id field at times has a second id. In this case, I need to create a new duplicated record and put a single id in each of the records.  There is an additional condition in which each of the ids may be followed by a number which is a percentage.  In all cases, I need to display the correct percentage as a decimal value in a field on the record.

id examples:

```
AJ01-25/ST01-75
AJ01/LM03
RICH01
```

Correct representation of ids and percentages:

```
id      percent
AJ01    .25
ST01    .75
AJ01    .5
LM03    .5
RICH01  1.0
```

I used the following code to create a new record and parse any percentages into a new field whenever a "/" is detected, but I'd very much like to have something cleaner.  Sort order does not matter (my script places new records at the end).  Thoughts?

```
Sub breakemup()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim id As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim ar() As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("data")

Dim currentRow As Integer
Dim finalRow As Integer
finalRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For currentRow = 2 To finalRow
    ar() = Split(ws.Range("a" & currentRow).Value, "/")
    If UBound(ar) = 1 Then
        ws.Rows(currentRow).Copy Destination:=ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        If UBound(Split(ar(1), "-")) = 1 Then
            ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value = Split(ar(1), "-")(0)
            ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = CDbl(Split(ar(1), "-")(1)) / 100#
            ws.Range("A" & currentRow).Value = Split(ar(0), "-")(0)
            ws.Range("A" & currentRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = CDbl(Split(ar(0), "-")(1)) / 100#
        Else
            ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value = ar(1)
            ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = 50 / 100#
            ws.Range("A" & currentRow).Value = ar(0)
            ws.Range("A" & currentRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = 50 / 100#
        End If
    Else
        ws.Range("A" & currentRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = 1#

    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you would consider this cleaner but here is a formula solution rather than a VBA one. It uses the functions:

1. INDIRECT
2. MID
3. LEN
4. IF
5. RIGHT
6. FIND

Lets say we have the following in sheet 1:

[image]

Insert the following formulas in sheet 2:

**Cell A2:**

=IF(E2=1, IF(D2="", IF(C2="", INDIRECT(G2), LEFT(INDIRECT(G2), C2-1)), LEFT(INDIRECT(G2), D2-1)),  IF(D2="",IF(C1="",  INDIRECT(G2), RIGHT(INDIRECT(G2), LEN(INDIRECT(G2))-C1)), MID(INDIRECT(G2), C1+1, D2 -1-C1)))

Drag / Copy it down to cover the rest of the cells in column A

**Cell B2:**

=IF(E2=1,IF(C2="",IF(D2="",1,MID(INDIRECT(G2),C2+1,LEN(INDIRECT(G2)))),IF(D2="",0.5,MID(INDIRECT(G2),D2+1,C2-D2-1)/100)),  IF(D2="",0.5,MID(INDIRECT(G2),D2+1, LEN(INDIRECT(G2))-D2)/100))

Drag / Copy it down to cover the rest of the cells in column B

**Cell C2:**

=IF(E2=1, IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("/",INDIRECT(G2))),FIND("/", INDIRECT(G2)), ""), "")

Drag / Copy it down to cover the rest of the cells in column C

**Cell D2:**

=IF(E2=1, IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-", INDIRECT(G2))),FIND("-", INDIRECT(G2)), ""),IF(D1 ="", "",  FIND("-", INDIRECT(G2), D1+1)))

Drag / Copy it down to cover the rest of the cells in column D

**Cell E2:**

The number value "1"

**Cell E3:**

=IF(E2=1, IF(C2="", 1, 2),1)

Drag / Copy it down to cover the rest of the cells in column E

**Cell F2:**

the number value "1"

**Cell F3:**

=IF(E3=1, F2+1, F2)

Drag / Copy it down to cover the rest of the cells in column F

**Cell G2:**

="Sheet1!A" & TEXT(F2, 0)

Drag / Copy it down to cover the rest of the cells in column G

**Result:**

[image]

You could hide the extra columns so you only see the columns you need:

[image]

I have an article on my blog that provides an example with pretty much the same functions used here, it might help with understanding the functions used [Excel Functions and Formulas Sample #1, Split Strings Based on Delimeter](http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/03/08/excel-functions-and-formulas-sample-1-split-strings-based-on-delimeter/)

Comment: Interesting solution!  I'm looking for pure VBA though.